# How to remove outer list?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have a simple example,
Create a program that asks the user for a number and then prints out a list of all the divisors of that number.

And i am solving it like this:

```
n = 4
list_range = list(range(1,n+1))
divisor_list = []
divisor_list.append([i for i in list_range if n%i==0])
print divisor_list
#output:
#[[1, 2, 4]]
```

I want the output to be `[1, 2, 4]`

I can achieve this by:

```
n = 4
list_range = list(range(1,n+1))
divisor_list = []
for i in list_range:
    if n % i == 0:
        divisor_list.append(i)
print divisor_list
#output:
#[1, 2, 4]
```

But is there a better way of achieving this ?

Comment: this might be belong on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: `divisor_list = [i for i in list_range if n%i==0]` or `divisor_list = [] divisor_list +=  [i for i in list_range if n%i==0]`

Comment: Thank you for your answers ... please don't down-vote ....

Comment: Except for n, no member of divisor_list can be greater than n/2, so why keep trying after that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes no sense to loop through all range of numbers, it's a waste! Just try to prove there are no more divisors after n/2, here's another benchmarked version comparing an alternative method `f2`:

```
import math
import timeit


def f1(num):
    return [i for i in range(1, num + 1) if num % i == 0]


def f2(num):
    square_root = int(math.sqrt(num)) + 1
    output = []
    for i in range(1, square_root):
        if (num % i == 0 and i * i != num):
            output.append(i)
            output.append(num / i)
        if (num % i == 0 and i * i == num):
            output.append(i)

    return output


def bench(f, N):
    for n in range(1, N):
        f(N)

N = 10000
print timeit.timeit('bench(f1, N)', setup='from __main__ import bench, f1, N', number=1)
print timeit.timeit('bench(f2, N)', setup='from __main__ import bench, f2, N', number=1)
```

Results on my cpu are:

```
4.39642974016
0.124005777533
```

f2 won't give a sorted list, but that's irrelevant, you didn't mention that in your question

Comment: can you please explain why is `f2` more performance efficient than `f1` ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `extend`:
`divisor_list.extend([i for i in list_range if n%i==0])`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need append, just use:

```
divisor_list = [i for i in list_range if n% i == 0]
```

This way you just assign the result of list comprehension, giving you one clean list. No need to append a list, that will nest a list in a list, and no need to initialize as an empty list. That's redundant because you add to the list just the next line. Just assign to list comprehension. As @joel goldstick mentioned, you can just loop over *half* of `list_range` because nothing will be a division if it's more than 1/2 the number:

```
list_range = list(range(1, (n / 2) + 1))
```

Comment: why go all the way to list_range, when half that will do?

Comment: @joelgoldstick Indeed, I think that's the most relevant thing to learn from the whole thread ;-) , I've also mentioned that in my answer

Comment: @AndrewL. Be aware `list(range(1, n / 2))` won't provide the expected result for all numbers, not downvoting though :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use assign the result of the list comprehension to the variable.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to initialize `divisor_list` as an empty sequence at all. The comprehension you're appending is the actual answer you're looking for.

```
divisor_list = [i for i in list_range if n%i==0]
```